# Why is Visual Studio Code Running Old Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm new to programming and have been practicing python for a few months now. One problem that I keep facing is when vscode executes old code. I have autosave on and have tried closing the program and opening it again. Currently, I have a totally different file open and its showing me TypeError associated with another file I was working on yesterday. The file that I'm running works perfectly fine in other text editors. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show more information about your error.

Comment: I'm not sure what more I could have shared regarding the error. As I said, it was related to another python file as the code in the current file actually ran without errors. I ended up just uninstalling vscode and reinstalling it again.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, assuming you are using `Run(Ctrl+F5 or F5)`, you are probably building off an old project. In Solution Explorer, when you choose or open the project/repository. It will run and build off of that project until you choose a new one. Just opening another file in the same window/solution will not change the build path.

Another solution you could try is to execute the program file from cmd line in the `` terminal(ctrl + `) ``.